# The chronograph instrument error is 0.01s, so why should 10 periods be measured in calculation?

Tags: experimental-physics

> The experimental subjects have a period of less than 0.1s, and the resolution is not enough. If only one cycle is measured, it will be greatly affected by chance.

how to figure it out? and also some description, please?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I want to know how many people visit a grocery store in a month. Here's one approach: I know that the store is scheduled to be open for 3600 minutes every month, so I can watch the door for one minute and extrapolate.

That's a *terrible* way to extrapolate, because the interval is too small. I might look for a minute where nobody comes, and extrapolate to "zero people will visit the store this month." I might happen to look for a minute where a family of seven arrives all at once, and extrapolate that 25,200 people will visit the store.  There's too much variation in that tiny interval for the extrapolation to be useful.

People-counting is different from frequency measurement (because people-arrivals are "Poisson distributed"), but the same general idea applies: lots of measurements are better than fewer measurements.  You describe a system with period 0.1s and a chronometer with precision 0.01s.  If you measure a single period, the best you could *possibly* do would be an uncertainty of 10%, which is like being uncertain whether your cartful of groceries will cost you \$100 or \$110.  (You don't say much about your setup, but if you have a hand-operated stopwatch which displays centi-seconds, your precision will be limited by your reaction time in pressing the "start" and "stop" buttons with your thumb. My experience is that students usually operate a stopwatch with quarter-second reaction-time noise.)

But, suppose instead that you count out 100 periods, and measure that much longer interval with a precision that is one-tenth of one period. Now your time measurement is good to one part in a thousand, like being uncertain whether your grocery bill will be \$100 or \$100.10.  If your lab partner were to say to you "hey I think that was only 99 periods," your measurement would *still* be better than your single-period measurement.

Ten periods is a good compromise position, because a well-done intro-lab experiment will typically have percent-scale uncertainties.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying assumption here is that chronometer is *accurate* (it measures time correctly over a sufficiently long interval) but not very *precise* (it cannot measure intervals of less than 0.1 seconds). Another way of putting this is that the observational errors made when the chronometer is used to measure intervals are *random* errors, rather than *systemic* errors.

If this is the case then using the chronometer to measure ten periods (if, indeed, all periods are the same length) and then dividing by ten to get an average measurement for one period will give a better estimate than trying to measure just one period on its own.